# vs2005 report designer : Remove or replace symbols and inside text

Tags: reporting-services, replace, visual-studio-2005

Good day.
I'm needing help regards this issue.
Replacing text or characters are quite easy.

```
=Replace(Fields!Content.Value,"~~~","-")
```

But how about random (%%) or unspecified text, or is it even possible?

How am I going to replace or remove **(**, **)** and any text between those two symbols?

Sample I have a **Field!Content.Value** in my dataset.
This column contain a hundreds of data or rows.
What I wanted is if it contains (anything) or (something)?

Examples:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                    Content                      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|          This sample is one (1) only            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|            Nothing (Wala) has change.           |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I wanted to have in my table rows

**This sample is one**  **only**

**Nothing**  **has change.**

as result

What expression will I use or How will I remove any word from my fetched data which starts from **(** and ends with **)**?
Please, anyone who could help or give comment regards my issue.

Thanks,

JSun

*Please, don't hesitate to edit my post if my format is not good, or change my tags if needed.*

Comment: You want to remove () from (xxx) and end up with xxx?

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to remove any text starts with ( and ends with ).
So if I'm having "Hello (World)" and "(Hello) World".
I will be having "Hello " and " World".

Comment: Will there be multiple `(...)` substrings within your field?

Comment: @IanPreston yes likely. My problem is that there's too many rows in the column which I must get rid of all comments: comments are determined by **(...)**. How am I supposed to do that automatically in my vs2005 report designer? any idea? please.

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember the exact format, but something like this:
    =Left(Fields!Content.Value, IndexOf(Fields!Content.Value,"(") - 1) + Right(Fields!Content.Value, Len(Fields!Content.Value) - IndexOf(Fields!Content.Value,")")

Take left of field from 1 to index of ( + right of field for field length minus index of )

Comment: vs2005 says IndexOf is and invalid modifier.

Comment: Like I said I can't remember the exact format, when you're typing the expression have a look at the string functions at the bottom, it's IndexOf or Index or something like that. When you single click on a function name it tells you on the right what the function does.